# Rxjs Scan method copies content of array property of Observable when new items added

Tags: arrays, angular, observable, rxjs5

In an Angular component I have a property of type `BehaviourSubject<IController>`:

```
controllerData$ = new BehaviourSubject<IController | null>(null);

IController {
  users: IUser[];
  showDetails: boolean;
}
```

I need to iterate over the users array of type `IUser` and execute an intermediate transformation over the property data before returning the results as array.
Below the code I use:

1. flatMap(): to flatten the IUsers[] items
2. map(): to iterate over the users and apply the intermediate processing
3. scan(): to pack the results into an array again

Below my code:

```
controllerData$                    
  .pipe(
        filter((input) => input !== null),
        flatMap((p) => {
            return p.users;
        }),
        map((m: IUser) => {
            const data = {m,
                    date: this.getWeekDay(m.occurrence),
                    nextOccurrence: this.service.getNextDate(m.frequency, m.occurrence),
                };
            return data;
         }),
        scan((acc: any, cur) => [...acc, cur], [])
        )
```

When the component loads the first time with two IUser items, everything works well. However when I add a new user to the array, the scan method copies also the previous array values, that is, having two initial items and adding a new one, I get 5 items in the array (the first two twice and the new one) instead of just three elements.

As a workaround I achieved it with the solution below, but **I was wondering whether I can skip the `foreach` loop and obtain everything with just Rxjs operators**:

```
.pipe(
        filter((input) => input !== null),
        map((m) => {
            const results: any[] = [];
            m.users.forEach((ctlr: IUser) => {
                results.push({
                    user: ctlr.user,
                    date: this.getWeekDay(ctlr.occurrence),
                    nextOccurrence: this.service.getNextDateOccurrence(ctlr.frequency, ctlr.occurrence),
                });
            });
            return results;
         }),
```

Comment: Why? rxjs operators are there to deal with observables, not to manipulate arrays. Don't try to use rxjs for things it isn't intended for. Your second solution is better, but I'd just use `Array#map` instead of `forEach`.

Comment: @Ingo: thanks for the confirmation and Array.map suggestion.